# How to select non-cosecutive cells in Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to do a `T.TEST` of the values in rows (2,3,8,9) vs. (4,5,6,7). I tried doing `T.TEST((D1:D2,D8:D9),D4:D7,2,2)` but Excel didn't like it. Is there a way to skip rows like that?

As a test I tried `SUM((D1:D2,D8:D9))` and did get the right result.

Answer (score 1):

`SUM` will work with non consecutive cell ranges also. But `TTEST` needs two matrices, either from consecutive cell ranges or from array literals like `{1;2;3;4}` or `{1,2,3,4}`.

So you could use `INDIRECT` in collaboration with `N` to create a matrice from a non consecutive cell range.

```
=TTEST(N(INDIRECT({"D2";"D3";"D8";"D9"})),D4:D7,2,2)
```

Since `TTEST` needs matrices there, it is in array context already. So this formula needs not be inputted as an array formula using [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter].

Note the "D2", "D3", ... within `INDIRECT` are text strings and **not** cell references. So they will not be updated if the formula is copied.